# What does merry mean in merry-go-round?

Tags: meaning

"merry-go-round" is a device in park ,it turn round or circle."merry" in "merry christmas" means happy or enjoy,is it the same meaning in "merry-go-round"?

Comment: _Merry_ is an adjective; it means _enjoyable_, not _enjoy_.  A roundabout/carousel turns people round for fun!

Comment: @KateBunting, though you’re no doubt right about *merry-go-round*, I’d point out that that sense of *merry* is quite rare these days and that much more often,  *merry* means more like *enjoy**ing*** than *enjoyable*. At least in the US.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum - OK - I was just emphasising the fact that it is an adjective and not a verb.

Comment: Did you check a reliable dictionary for "merry"? What did you find? What are you unsure about?

Answer (score 1):

This is one compound word "merry-go-round" and not three words.

A "go-(a)round" (meaning an act of turning or rotation, or a device for causing rotation) is a phrase from Victorian times (it is commonly used in aviation, perhaps as "go around"), hence a "Merry-go-round" is a "go-round" that is for fun.  The etymology of "merry" in "merry-go-round" is the same as in "Merry Christmas".